# Apparent memory leak in FastEnumeration when deriving from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I have a class that acts as a subclass of NSMutableDictionary (mostly by delegation) as we have some custom interfaces wrapped around a dictionary.  When running the ios leak instrument it is identifying my keyEnumerator method as the source of the leak of NSFastEnumerationEnumerator objects.

Here is my keyEnumeration method as a delegate for the wrapped NSMutableDictionary.

```
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator {
    return [dictionary keyEnumerator];
}
```

The backtrace for the leak always shows an enumerator as the source:

```
- (void) someMethod {
    for (NSString *key in myWrappedDictionary) { ... }
}
```

Here is a typical backtrace:

```
calloc
class_createInstance
__CFAllocateObject2
-[__NSCFDictionary keyEnumerator]
-[WrappedDictionary keyEnumerator]
-[NSDictionary countByEnumerating...
-[SomeClass someMethod]
```

I'm looking for a workaround or flaw in my one line of code.  I'm using ARC.

An example class is shown below.  Invoking [WrappedDictionary createLeaks] will create 9 leaks.

```
@interface WrappedDictionary : NSMutableDictionary {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
}
- (id) init;
- (NSUInteger) count;
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator;
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)key;
@end
@implementation WrappedDictionary
- (id) init  {
    dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    return self;
}
- (NSUInteger) count { return [dictionary count]; }
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator {
    return [dictionary keyEnumerator];
}
- (void)setObject: anObject forKey:key {
    [dictionary setObject:anObject forKey: key];
}
+ (void) createLeaks {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        WrappedDictionary *dict = [WrappedDictionary new];
        [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"1"];
        [dict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"2"];
        [dict setObject:@"3" forKey:@"3"];
        for (NSString *key in dict) {
            NSLog(@"key=%@",key);
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the leaks instrument just shows where a leaked piece of memory is *allocated*. That doesn't mean that the allocation point is the source of the leak. The more likely source of the leak is in `someMethod`, or in the caller of `someMethod`, particularly if you put this into an ivar and then have a retain cycle on the entire object.

Comment: The leaked object is a NSFastEnumerationEnumerator instance which I don't have a handle to since it's created and used implicitly by the for loop.  Every place I have an iterator on the collection shows a leak.

Comment: So your subclass is both IS-A NSDictionary, and HAS-A NSDictionary? And you've overridden count, objectForKey: and keyEnumerator to delegate to the HAS-A? Do you have a simple version that demonstrates?

Comment: How are you determining that the above code leaks? When I toss it into a small iOS project, I don't see any leaks in Instruments. Which SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm running it on an ipod using the leaks Instrument to start the app.  I have it hooked to a button press and the leaks summary show it after the 10 second snapshot.

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce on a 5.1 iPhone4. I'm using a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:15 to get it after the first snapshot. Not seeing any leaks. Maybe the specific OS version?

Comment: Updated ipod touch to ios 5.1 and still see leak

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a simple workaround.

If I change the keyEnumerator method from

```
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator {
    return [dictionary keyEnumerator];
}
```

to

```
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator {
    NSEnumerator *e = [dictionary keyEnumerator];
    return e;
}
```

the leak goes away.  This still does not make sense to me but it apparently forces the compiler to ARC properly the return from dictionary.

Comment: I have a similar problem here, do you know why the local variable trick fixed the memory leak?

Comment: I can only presume that there is a bug in ARC and the local variable somehow triggers the compiler to 'do good'.  Hopefully the workaround will work for you too.